# FATAL: role "MYUSERNAME" does not exist

Tags: psql, mac-os-x

I am new to *psql* and am trying to set it up using the [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com) site on my Mac. After installation and opening *psql*, this is the message I get:

> Last login: Sat May 21 07:10:21 on ttys000
>   '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin'/psql -p5432
>   MacBook-Pro:~ MYUSERNAME$ '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin'/psql -p5432
>   psql: FATAL:  role "MYUSERNAME" does not exist

Using the [troubleshooting section](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/troubleshooting.html) I used to the server manual for more information on the issue. This is the result:

> MacBook-Pro:~ MYUSERNAME$ /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/postgres -D "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.5"
>   FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
>   HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 1813) running in data directory "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.5"?

Has anybody got any suggestions how I could proceed?